# Auxiliary Space Complexity of Dictionaries whose Keys are Iterables of Variable Size

Tags: space-complexity, big-o-notation, python, dictionaries

Recently, I began delving into complexity analysis with dictionaries. More specifically, I have been looking at auxiliary space complexity. For the most part, this type of analysis has been straightforward. For instance, suppose we have the following function `foo`, which takes in an integer `n`:

```
def foo(n):
   d = {}

   for i in range(n):
      d[i] = 0
   
   return d
```

In a simple example like this, it is clear that the auxiliary space complexity is `O(N)`, since the function will be creating a dictionary that contains `n` key-value pairs. Most problems that I have encountered follow this model, where a given key is mapped to a "singular" object (usually a number).

What I find more complicated, however, is attempting to navigate dictionaries whose keys map to iterables, which we extend/modify throughout the algorithm.

Suppose, for instance, that we are considering the function `bar`, which takes in an array of integers:

```
def bar(nums):
    d = {}
    
    for num in nums:
        if num not in d:
           d[num] = []
        d[num].append(num)

    return d
```

In such a scenario, how do we discuss auxiliary space complexity? My guess is to view each key as a data "unit" and each element in each created list as a data "unit". In the worst case, we would have `N` keys in our dictionary (where `N` is the size of our input list), each mapping to a list of length 1. In total, therefore, there are `2N` data "units" expended (`N` keys and `N` elements across all of our value lists), which is just `O(N)`. In this case, how we choose to interpret keys and values will not impact our conclusion about auxiliary space. However, I can foresee situations where this may not be the case.

Is there a more proper way of thinking about auxiliary space complexity in these types of scenarios? Or, should I continue to think about a key as a data "unit" and each element in each iterable as a data "unit"?